# What LEGO clone brand are these with 4-peg studs?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I think this was a present in the mid-late 80s.

Very sophisticated building blocks for top-view apartment-room design. They also had furniture and appliances. Can anyone tell me the brand etc?

[image]

Comment: You might find it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120730061221/http://www.freewebs.com/orrex/constructionclones.htm

Comment: Do you know which country they were sold in?

Comment: I believe they were italian.

Comment: Maybe a quick seach on wikipedia:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Construction_toys

Comment: These do not match any entry on the above Wikipedia link. Can you provide better pictures of the blocks themselves ? Anything written on them? Any paper, cardboard piece ? Can you picture the different types of bricks present in this photo ?

Answer (score 2):

They look similar to Arckit, but the "stud" placement is different.
Perhaps you have a picture of an earlier design?

https://www.dezeen.com/2015/05/24/architect-modelling-system-arckit-posh-lego-damien-murtagh/
https://us.arckit.com/