# Can anyone identify the brand of this non-LEGO brick with grooved sides and a lion logo?

Tags: part-identification

Hi folks I was hoping someone out there may recognise the brand of this block I found in the garden. I have been searching but [the closest I can find are Locblocks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/please-help-identify-this-vintage-but-non-lego-brick?noredirect=1&lq=1) - however this appears to have a Lion logo embossed on the top.

[image: top with Lion logo]

[image: bottom]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please help identify this vintage (but non-Lego) brick!](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/please-help-identify-this-vintage-but-non-lego-brick)

Comment: I did see that post Phil but this is slightly different to the one posted there. It's more the brand I'm looking for so I can possibly put a date to it. I hoped the Lion on top would help to identify it.

Comment: Hi JayJ - can you include the dimensions of the brick? Or perhaps add a comparison photo alongside a LEGO 2x4?

Comment: Hi JayJ, where is the garden where you found it? UK, Canada, China, etc.?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, time got away on me. Mike, sorry I forgot to mention I'm in Bendigo, Australia.  Ben, 31x15mm base and 9mm high.

Comment: There is a lion on the top so that might give you a clue

Comment: I have performed numerous internet searches that include the word 'lion' but have had no luck so far.

Comment: It looks more like a seal than a lion to me.

Comment: Thanks mindstormsboi, I'll hava a look.

Answer (score 1):

Hang on - I recognize this! This is definitely from a knock-off brand my brother got a few months ago for his birthday. It's either from a brand called OXFORD in South Korea or from Coco, an illegal (i think) Chinese Knock-off.