# Can anyone identify these two makers marks (logos) on these "Clone" bricks?

Tags: clone-brands

This may seem a bit weird but over a number of years I've saved a small collection of random Lego bricks I've found among driftwood/debris along the Ohio River bank, after rises and falls of the river. I enjoy collecting pieces of driftwood, and occasionally find fishing lures, bobbers  and other odds and ends in my hikes. So recently, I was studying them closely and noticed a few are competitor brands including Mega Bloks and Tyco. But I can't figure out what the brand is of these two, with different logos on them. I will attach a pic of each logo. I tried to get the pics sharp and clear enough to make out. One of them  is on the bottom and looks like an "A F" inside of a circle. The other appears on the top. It seems like it is familiar but I can't place it. Neither one of these bricks has any logo or lettering on the studs. Any ideas on maker or brand name?? Thanks!!

EDIT -  An additional comment, added 7/4/21: Just added three more pics to show the bricks with the "AF in a circle" logo on bottom (the group of four). Although the red brick has it marked "correctly", all three blue ones have the AF circle logo backwards! Including pics showing both the top and bottom of the bricks. Don't know what type of plastic they are made from, but they have that softer, sorta "waxy" feel something like the PP (number 5) plastic. These were probably found in the 1990s.

[image: A F in circle on bottom]
[image: Blue brick with AF inside circle but this one is reversed]
[image: Blue & Red bricks with AF inside circle, top view]
[image: Blue & Red bricks with AF inside circle, bottom view]
[image: Logo on top of red 2 by 4 brick]

Comment: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/please-help-identify-this-vintage-but-non-lego-brick

Answer (score 8):

According to [an earlier question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/please-help-identify-this-vintage-but-non-lego-brick), the second is

> a Kawada Dia Block made in Japan. Entex and Sears imported those into the US in the 70’s and 80’s and repackaged them under such brands as Loc Bloc and Brix Blox. The “S” is actually a K on top of a D, which is the emblem for the Japanese toy company Kawada. Dia Blocks are still made and available in Japan today.

Comment: Thank you RSchulz for the link and the help!   Now that I know what one of the brick's maker is (Kawada of Japan) I would still love to find out what the "A F inside a circle" stands for, which is on the other 4 bricks (3 blue, one red)!!   I'm sure someone out there knows!