# Identify brand of this non-LEGO 2x4 plate

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I found this on my old desk and then I remembered that I used to buy fake LEGO sets with parts like this. Maybe someone knows what the name of the brand that produces parts like this (I don't know if it's made in China or not but mostly from there)

Edit: the scale is the same as the real LEGO pieces, it doesn't have any emblem on the stud or part id.

Edit2: okay i add another pic and a vehicle set with a sticker. I try to rebuild it as i could remember it

Edit3: it was Chaobao but i need your help to find some information about this brand

[image: the non-lego part]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, it fits with Lego? If not, could you include with a piece of Lego for scale? And please include a photo of the other side, since many manufacturers put an emblem in the stud (like Lego does with their logo).

Comment: Nope it's not fit, also there's no emblem either. The backside is the only clue to identify the brand

Comment: That looks suspiciously similar to the kawada/locbloc from [this other question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/please-help-identify-this-vintage-but-non-lego-brick?rq=1) - not just the two strips, but the six small ridges at each side. It'd be nice to have a clear macro photograph of the top of the plate to see if there's an embossed logo as well.

Comment: there's nothing on the top of the plate/stud. that's why i took the picture only underside

Comment: Take a picture of the top anyways. And one by the side, to compare the height (and bevel) of the studs against known brands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found it, It was Chaobao. I was searching through the images on google then i found this pic, i recognize those wheel and the slope pieces (it even had the same horizontal line on the pic above).

I'm really sure this was the brand but i need more information about this Chaobao because because they have no official website or anything.

[image]

Comment: That's a bit of a stretch - there might be other manufacturers with the same wheel mold. It is true, however, that chaobao seems to be using "slotted" plate undersides, as noted in https://www.reddit.com/r/buildingblocks/comments/2dr5vg/brand_highlight_chaobao/ckk35j1/?context=3

Comment: @IvanSanchez maybe, but i still need more info. Do you know someone who maybe listing every chaobao brick set?

Comment: Sadly set databases for clone brands are basically non-existant.  The most comprehensive resource I know of is [Communist LEGO](https://brickset.com/article/38929/a-survey-of-communist-lego-2018) and they don't mention this brand that I've found.

Comment: @chicks Yeah, this is my only hope so that I can rebuild all of the fake lego set that I have